# startLeScan replacement to current api

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Goal is to read the values of a bluetooth LE heart rate monitor.

Using google's sample, I get

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

which causes `mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan` to be shown as deprecated. Startscan is no method of `mBluetoothAdapter` though.

How to change this for it to work with the current API?

Comment: after a year the same sample is still deprecated, why they don't make an update?..

Comment: Good point, when I work at Google, I'll keep the documentation updated. I got here because I can't find how either :p

Answer (score 28):

Both methods[BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) and [BluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#stopLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)) were deprecated in Android Lollipop. As a replacement [BluetoothLeScanner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) were introduced and acting as a scan controller.

If you develop BLE-based application you should control either scan via the BluetoothAdapter (Android 4.3 and Android 4.4) or the BluetoothLeScanner. The API introduced in Android Lollipop offers much greater features in terms of battery power consumption.

Comment: Can I use BluetoothLeScanner in Android 4.3 (compile with Lollipop but min SDK is set to 18)?

Comment: @Fei it's impossible to use BluetoothLeScanner on OS version lower than API 21. This class simply will not be present in Android SDK on those devices. The attempt to perform BLE scan on them will result in ClassNotFoundException thrown.

Answer (score 27):

Thank you all for your responses. To Summarize the answer to this question I'll add my final code snippet.

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;


private ScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
}


private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

    final BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;

                bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()` to get an instance of BluetoothLeScanner.

Then, you can start or stop a scan with the `startScan` or `stopScan` methods, much like the deprecated version.

Difference is you can pass scanfilters and settings. The ScanCallback has more info about found devices. Filters allow you to filter scanresults based on name, macaddress, service UUIDs etc. Scan settings allow you to control scanning power.

Comment: Using `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;` I only get `.getDefaultAdapter()` and not `.getBluetoothLeScanner()`. Therefore I don't get `startScan` but only the deprecated methods mentioned.

Comment: Do you have target SDK set to 21? And do you have an instance of BluetoothAdapter to obtain the BluetoothLeScanner?

Answer (score 6):

Remember that the method:

```
public BluetoothLeScanner getBluetoothLeScanner ()
```

isn't static. If you do:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner()
```

you will get an error, since getDefaultAdapter() is a static method, but getBluetoothLeScanner() isn't.

You need an instance of a BluetoothAdapter. You can get one by doing:

```
(BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE).getAdapter()
```

That way, you can try:

```
Context mContext = getBaseContext();
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner mLeScanner = mAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

mLeScanner.startScan(...);
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the warning. Just check API version before call the function. You can use the code

```
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;
private ScanCallback scanCallback;
private ScanSettings scanSetting;

// Check before call the function
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filterList, scanSetting, scanCallback);
        } else {
            bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        }
```