# Android ble scan don't find devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to an ble device, so I've implemented a bluetooth ble scan activity for this, but this does not work on my tablet (Archos 70 3G with android 7.0) but works in my phone (Xiaomi Note 8 Pro). I allowed location and bluetooth both devices. What is the problem? The code of the activity:

```
package myapp

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import myapp.R;

public class BluetoothListActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    // private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private TextView mEmptyList;
    public static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";

    List<BluetoothDevice> deviceList;
    private DeviceAdapter deviceAdapter;
    private ServiceConnection onService = null;
    Map<String, Integer> devRssiValues;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000; //scanning for 10 seconds
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mScanning;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] Results) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Git gud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "git gud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);
        android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        layoutParams.y = 200;
        mHandler = new Handler();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ble not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        populateList();
        mEmptyList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mScanning == false) scanLeDevice(true);
                else finish();
            }
        });

    }

    private void populateList() {
        /* Initialize device list container */
        Log.d(TAG, "populateList");
        deviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(this, deviceList);
        devRssiValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        scanLeDevice(true);

    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    cancelButton.setText(R.string.scan);

                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            cancelButton.setText(R.string.cancel);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            cancelButton.setText(R.string.scan);
        }

    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            addDevice(device, rssi);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    private void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
        boolean deviceFound = false;

        for (BluetoothDevice listDev : deviceList) {
            if (listDev.getAddress().equals(device.getAddress())) {
                deviceFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }


        devRssiValues.put(device.getAddress(), rssi);
        if (!deviceFound) {
            deviceList.add(device);
            mEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

    }

    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            BluetoothDevice device = deviceList.get(position);
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, deviceList.get(position).getAddress());

            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtras(b);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + deviceList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    };


    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
    }

    class DeviceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context context;
        List<BluetoothDevice> devices;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public DeviceAdapter(Context context, List<BluetoothDevice> devices) {
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.devices = devices;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return devices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return devices.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewGroup vg;

            if (convertView != null) {
                vg = (ViewGroup) convertView;
            } else {
                vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_list_element, null);
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = devices.get(position);
            final TextView tvadd = ((TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.address));
            final TextView tvname = ((TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.name));
            final TextView tvpaired = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.paired);
            final TextView tvrssi = (TextView) vg.findViewById(R.id.rssi);

            tvrssi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            byte rssival = (byte) devRssiValues.get(device.getAddress()).intValue();
            if (rssival != 0) {
                tvrssi.setText("Rssi = " + String.valueOf(rssival));
            }

            tvname.setText(device.getName());
            tvadd.setText(device.getAddress());
            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "device::" + device.getName());
                tvname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvadd.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvpaired.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                tvpaired.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvpaired.setText(R.string.paired);
                tvrssi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvrssi.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            } else {
                tvname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvadd.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvpaired.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvrssi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvrssi.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            return vg;
        }
    }

    private void showMessage(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please check if this is your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223071/startlescan-replacement-to-current-api), also, please update the question with your manifest permission(s), and the minimum version you require. If I am not mistaken, in Android L (API 22) the BluetoothLE was an adapter itself, that handles collisions with the actual adapter and other Bluetooth usage. Finally, what devices are you scanning? Do you have the fonts to them? What scenarios work? what doesn't? Are there any logs or additional information?

Comment: A [mcve] would be much better than all that extra code. See also [ask].